# Ethernet setup for point to point connection

Tags: ping, ethernet

I'm trying to debug a point-to-point ethernet interface which is not working, and I'm beginning to suspect that things have changed in Windows since I last tried this.

I have built a board with a fixed IP address, and am hooking it up to my laptop for testing.  Although the LEDs seem to blink, and my board manages to negotiate a physical connection, when I try to ping it from the PC, it fails.  The same PC successfully manages to ping a second PC with a fixed IP address.  Let me explain:

The TCP/IPv4 adapter settings on the PC are:

IP address;   192.168.1.5
Network mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: undefined

The board has:

IP address;   192.168.1.2
Network mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.

When I try to ping the board from the PC, I get "Destination host unreachable" some of the time, "Request timed out" the rest  I expect if there's a difficulty to always get "Request timed out".  The "Destination host unreachable" has me confused.  According to Microsoft, this message means nothing is being put out on the wire, and to try the route utility.  I tried to "Route add 192.168.1.2 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0 IF 6", and several other attempts, including using NirSoft's NetRouteView to add a route, and it fails, with "The parameter is incorrect".

When I take a second PC and set it to

IP address;   192.168.1.2
Network mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: undefined

Then pinging works, which disagrees with the "Destination host unavailable" which I am seeing when the board is attached (the route is there).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With a direct, point-to-point connection you can't ping a second PC - where do you connect it to?

Check `arp -a` to see if the destination IP address has been resolved to a MAC address. If not, the 'board' is likely configured to another IP address or not at all (waiting for DHCP, running zeroconf, ...).

You don't need any routes with both nodes directly connected to each other (or through a switch).

Comment: I replace the board with a second PC and set the second PC to the boards IP address.  Connect the two PCs with the same cross-cable that connected the PC and the board.  They can ping one another.  The PC alone connected to the board cannot, and although the board seems to see the physical connection (the PHY has passed the HW connection functions and has turned on the LED), the PC which it is connected to momentarily shows activity and then shows "Ethernet disconnected" and pinging fails - in the way described above.